# How to turn off webdriver mode in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I found an option that turns it off:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
options.set_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled', False)
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", ua)
options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
options.set_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled', False)
options.set_preference("useAutomationExtension", False)


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
action=ActionChains(driver)
driver.get('https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html')
```

But any way I get this:
[image]

How to turn it off and make browser undetectable?

Comment: What for? Maybe better to not use selenium? It made to test web sites. Please explain your purposes to help you.

Comment: Since you use selenium you use a webdriver. Just in Chrome you got perfect result https://ibb.co/nM7N3dw

Comment: Sorry but I want to use Firefox, but I can't off webdriver mode

Comment: Selenium uses webdriver by default no mater is it firefox and chrome.